# Next js Dynamic route is lost on page reload

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, redux, dynamic, next.js, reload

I am trying to fetch data from firestore and dispatch it to redux store, this works well, but whenever I reload the page the dynamic route is lost.

I tried to use `serverSideProps`, but it didn't solve the issue.

Here it is the code:

../pages/products/[id]

```
function Listing({ id }) {
  // fetching data from redux store
  const products = useSelector(selectDB);

  // searching for the page id in products
  const page = products.find((x) => x.title === id);
  // fallback state
  if (!page) {
    return <p className="text-5xl ">loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{page.title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Listing;

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { params } = context;

  const id = params.id;

  return {
    props: {
      id,
    },
  };
}
```

I want to solve the issue of the lost dynamic route on page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

after multiple attempts and thoughts, I found out that if I fetch the data directly from firestore the the dynamic page reloaded dynamic page will not be lost.

here is my solution :

```
    function Listing({ page }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{page.title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Listing;

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "products"));

  const products = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data() }));

  const { params } = context;

  const id = params.id;
  const page = products.find((x) => x.title === id);
  if (!page) return { notFound: true };

  return {
    props: { page },
  };
}
```

Comment: can you suggest a better format?